# Jquery Nav Detecting Screen Sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm encountering a slight problem with my navigation. When I resize my browser to check the mobile menu and click the 'header' a couple times for the dropdown menu, then resize my page back to a tablet or desktop size, my navigation disappears. This problem resolves itself if I delete this segment of code:

```
if ( width == GetWidth() ) {
    return;
}
width = GetWidth();
```

But I need this section of code so the navigation does not disappear when I scroll down on mobile.

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function(){
var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 600px)");

if (isMobile.matches) {
$('#mobile_active li a').on('click',function() {    
$('.Back a').text('Back');
$('#mobile_active li ul li a').slideToggle(150);
e.preventDefault();
});
}

$(window).resize(function(){
if ( width == GetWidth() ) {
    return;
}
width = GetWidth();

if( $(window).width() < 600) {
    $('#mobile_active').hide();
} else {
    $('#mobile_active').show();
}
}); 

$('header').on('click', function() {
$('#mobile_active').slideToggle(500);
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Any advice or input would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use CSS media queries for all of it? Using JS as a crutch for the UI is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use media queries for the mobile view - I actually thought I needed jquery to activate my mobile menu (click on the 'header' and the menu appears)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree you should use media queries and javascript for this type of thing, but I think I have found the cause of your issue.

When in mobile mode you have a click event attached to your `<header>` with a `slideToggle`. This `slideToggle` sets an inline style of `display:block;` or `display:none;` on the `#mobile_active` after it animates; depending on wether its closed or opened. When you resize to desktop size the `#mobile_active` still has an inline style of `display:none;` which is why you can not see it any more.

It looks like you may have code to correct this on your `resize` event:

```
if( $(window).width() < 600) {
    $('#mobile_active').hide();
} else {
    $('#mobile_active').show();
}
```

I think it just needs placed **before** this code block:

```
if ( width == GetWidth() ) {
    return;
}
width = GetWidth();
```

Which may be why when you remove it, it works

Comment: Works on the desktop, but now I'm losing my menu whenever I scroll down with my phone.

Comment: @user3022185 That maybe a separate issue. If you open a new question and isolate the problem in a fiddle I may be able to help you

Comment: I've made a new question and a fiddle:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209159/jquery-isolating-screen-size-issue
Thanks a lot for your time and patience!